# Java parallelizing combination using fork/join

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, combinatorics, fork-join

I am trying to parallelize a combinatorial optimization problem. Basically, I want to go through each combination of size k (n choose k) and see if the combination is the best. I wrote a sequential version that works (here's the java code):

```
public int bestCombo(int[] al, int[] data, int start, int end, int index, int k) {
    if (index == k) {
        // you have unique combination
        return calculateBestCombination(data);
    } else {
        int best = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end && end-i+1 >= k-index; i ++){
            data[index] = al[i];
            int temp = bestCombo(al, data, i+1, end, index+1, k);
            if (best < temp) {
              best = temp
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}
```

So my code does the computation at the leaf of the recursion tree where at the leaf, I will have a unique combination of size k, simple enough. Now I converted this into the fork/join code and I am not getting the correct solution. Here is my fork/join code in java code:

```
public class ParallelizeCombo extends RecursiveTask<MintSolution> {
    private int[] array;
    private int[] data;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int index;
    private int k;

    public ParallelizeCombo(int[] arr, int[] data, int start, int end, int index, int k) {
        super();
        this.array = arr;
        this.data = data;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.index = index;
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    protected int compute() {
        // base case, we have reached the end of the combo
        if (this.index == k) {
            return calculateBestCombination(this.data);
        } else {
            List<ParallelizeCombo> subtasks = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = this.start; i <= this.end && this.end-i + 1 >= this.r-this.index; i ++) {
                this.data[this.index] = this.array[i];
                ParallelizeCombo pc = new ParallelizeCombo(this.array, this.data, i+1, this.end, this.index+1, this.k);
                subtasks.add(pc);
            }
            // run subtasks
            for (ParallelizeCombo subtask: subtasks) {
                subtask.fork();
            }
            int best = 0;
            // join the subtasks
            for (ParallelizeCombo subtask: subtasks) {
                int temp = subtask.join();
                if (best < int) {
                    best = int
                }
            }
            return best;
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused because the code are basically the same. The only difference is that in the for loop in fork/join, I run it in multi-thread. However, the solution I get are completely different and the fork/join solution is very wrong. Anyone knows why?

Comment: If you are mutating you arrays in different threads then you have a massive issue. This seems like a very simple task for the Simplex algorithm - why not simply use an optimisation library?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I am an idiot... The problem is the following:

```
public ParallelizeCombo(int[] arr, int[] data, int start, int end, int index, int k) {
    super();
    this.array = arr;
    this.data = data;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.index = index;
    this.k = k;
}
```

Here, this.data is not creating a new data but merely pointing to data (by reference). Thus, when you calculateBestCombination on data at a particular time, it may not be the combination you think it is (other thread might have changed the value of data already).